# Best way to add licence key for module in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I want to restrict module for one domain per one license key in Prestashop, anyone can help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did this using IonCube and Dynamic key feature.

You have to encode main php file using ionCube and check domain during installation

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try!